# Custom view not working in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom view. I added below line for the view in Layout XML
    **xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto**

```
<RelattiveLayout  xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<com.clippingtest.ViewClip
    android:layout_below="@id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</com.clippingtest.ViewClip>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Added that view in MainActivity. I works fine in all version, except Lollipop. it show InflateException in this line ( '  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);' ), and app crash immediately in lollipop. How i create custom view for lollipop.

CustomViewCode:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int width = getWidth();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0,0);
    path.lineTo(width-180, 80);
    path.lineTo(width, 60);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

}
```

error Code:

```
   06-27 17:31:44.365  28812-28812/com.clippingtest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.clippingtest, PID: 28812
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.clippingtest/com.clippingtest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.clippingtest.ViewClip
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.clippingtest.ViewClip
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:616)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
        at com.clippingtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
```

at

```
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
```

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:495)
        at
```

Comment: show the code of that custom view

Comment: add trace(log from log.cat), and code of your custom view

Comment: post total error log

Comment: android:layout_below="@id/tv" where is that tv

Comment: You should tell us which method is missing, i.e. show the full exception trace. It probably will be something like ViewClip(Context,AttributeSet).

Comment: added layout_below. but it shows error @NoName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a constructor which looks like this:

```
public ViewClip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

This is clear from the stack trace:
`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]`

says that the `<init>` (constructor) with `Context` and `AttributeSet` parameter types is missing.

Comment: Thanks wujek. It working in view inflate in Activity. but it not work  in Fragment (onCreateView)

Comment: You should show the new exception trace, then. As you see from your initial question, people can only answer if you provide all the necessary information. 'It doesn't work' doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: Ok @wujek, i will sent

Answer (score 1):

try after adding this constructor

```
public ViewClip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    }
```

Comment: No, it crash again. it shows error in setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);